# Declaring char hexadecimal constants in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, char, hex

In various low-level parts of our code, we are required to send specific bytes to a device in order to make things happen.  As such, we have plenty of code that looks like:

```
const char magic_bytes[] = { 0x01, 0xFA, 0x92 };
```

Which results in the error (on GCC 4.7.2)

```
test_char.cpp:6:51: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘250’ from ‘int’ to ‘const char’ inside { } is ill-formed in C++11 [-Wnarrowing]
```

Since 0xFA is outside the range -128 to 127.

There are two workarounds that I can think of:

```
const char magic_bytes[] = { static_cast<char>(0x01), static_cast<char>(0xFA), static_cast<char>(0x92) };
```

or:

```
const unsigned char magic_bytes[] = { 0x01, 0xFA, 0x92 };
```

Both of which are either ugly (the first case), or have other drawbacks (having to cast to (const char*) in the case of the latter)

Is there a better way to declare these strings?

Comment: since you're technically working with `unsigned char`s, why do you need to cast to `char`? There's not really a neater solution, short of hiding the conversions with macros.

Comment: @Dave: Sadly, the universal symbol for "array of bytes" in C and C++ is `char *`, not `unsigned char *`. So that's why you usually need the cast. Yes, it really ought to be `void *`, but many APIs take `char*`s instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 gives you [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) support having existed for some time) to solve this problem.

```
template <typename... A>                                                                 
constexpr std::array<char, sizeof...(A)> byte_array(A... v)                              
{ return std::array<char, sizeof...(A)>{{static_cast<char>(v)...}}; }                    

constexpr auto arr = byte_array( 0x01, 0xFA, 0x92 );
```

Or to avoid repeatedly calling `.data()` for passing it to C funcs:

```
template <std::size_t S>
struct byte_array {
  char data_[S];
  char *data() { return data_; }
  operator char*() { return data_; }

  const char *data() const { return data_; }
  operator const char*() const { return data_; }

  constexpr std::size_t size() const { return S; }

  // one could add support for begin/end and things like that
};

template <typename... A>
constexpr byte_array<sizeof...(A)> make_byte_array(A... v)
{ return byte_array<sizeof...(A)>{{static_cast<char>(v)...}}; }

// beside constexpr, this can be also non-const
auto magic_bytes = make_byte_array( 0x01, 0xFA, 0x92 );
strtok(magic_bytes, "why?");
```

There is no overhead comparing to the plain char array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to have a single cast:

```
const unsigned char magic_bytesUC[] = { 0x01, 0xFA, 0x92 };
enum { NBYTES = sizeof(magic_bytesUC) };
const char *magic_bytes = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(magic_bytesUC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified C++11, I'll assume you can use [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html). In which case there is a solution which is elegant when used, but as ugly as they come behind-the-scenes.

So I'll begin by showing you how you'd use it:

```
char myBytes1[] = MAKE_BYTES( 0x00, 0x40, 0x80, 0xC0 );
char myBytes2[] = MAKE_BYTES( 0xFF );
```

And now, the backend code: This could be shorter, but I've used standard looping methods so you could get some reuse out of it. It can support 1 - 24 byte lists. It can be made bigger than that by repeating the final lines some more. Welcome to the world of pre-processor meta-programming.

```
#define EXPAND(a) a
#define ARGS_COUNT_(\
  _96,_95,_94,_93,_92,_91,_90,_89,_88,_87,_86,_85,_84,_83,_82,_81,\
  _80,_79,_78,_77,_76,_75,_74,_73,_72,_71,_70,_69,_68,_67,_66,_65,\
  _64,_63,_62,_61,_60,_59,_58,_57,_56,_55,_54,_53,_52,_51,_50,_49,\
  _48,_47,_46,_45,_44,_43,_42,_41,_40,_39,_38,_37,_36,_35,_34,_33,\
  _32,_31,_30,_29,_28,_27,_26,_25,_24,_23,_22,_21,_20,_19,_18,_17,\
  _16,_15,_14,_13,_12,_11,_10, _9, _8, _7, _6, _5, _4, _3, _2, _1,\
  N,...) N
#define ARGS_COUNT(...) ARGS_COUNT_(__VA_ARGS__,\
  96,95,94,93,92,91,90,89,88,87,86,85,84,83,82,81,\
  80,79,78,77,76,75,74,73,72,71,70,69,68,67,66,65,\
  64,63,62,61,60,59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49,\
  48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,\
  32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,\
  16,15,14,13,12,11,10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
#define ARGS_HEAD(a,...) (a)
#define ARGS_TAIL(a,...) (__VA_ARGS__)

#define FOREACH(macro,lmacro,list) FOREACH_(ARGS_COUNT list,macro,lmacro,list)
#define FOREACH_(n,macro,lmacro,list) FOREACH__(n,macro,lmacro,list)
#define FOREACH__(n,macro,lmacro,list) FOREACH_##n(macro,lmacro,list)
#define FOREACH_1(macro,lmacro,list) lmacro list
#define FOREACH_2(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_1(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_3(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_2(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_4(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_3(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_5(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_4(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_6(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_5(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_7(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_6(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_8(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_7(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_9(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_8(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_10(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_9(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_11(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_10(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_12(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_11(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_13(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_12(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_14(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_13(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_15(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_14(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_16(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_15(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_17(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_16(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_18(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_17(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_19(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_18(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_20(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_19(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_21(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_20(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_22(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_21(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_23(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_22(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)
#define FOREACH_24(macro,lmacro,list) EXPAND(macro ARGS_HEAD list) FOREACH_23(macro,lmacro,ARGS_TAIL list)

#define MAKE_BYTE(x) static_cast<char>(x),
#define MAKE_LAST_BYTE(x) static_cast<char>(x)
//#define MAKE_BYTES(x) { FOREACH(MAKE_BYTE,MAKE_LAST_BYTE,x) } // uncomment this if you would rather use double bracket ((0x00,0x40,...)) syntax
#define MAKE_BYTES(...) { FOREACH(MAKE_BYTE,MAKE_LAST_BYTE,(__VA_ARGS__)) }
```

Comment: Are the variadic macros backwards compatible with C++03? Or, acceptable to us, were they introduced as a GCC extension in earlier versions (say, GCC 4.2)?

Comment: @Damien: Yes (a GCC extension), although if you go back far enough the syntax changes to named parameters, with `nameOfArgs...`. In my projects I have checks to swap over the variadic macros (and I use the commented form from the last lines to keep all changes in the common bits), but that obviously means much more code. The problem is this wasn't standardised until C99, and C++11. I don't know how long the standards-compliant form has been in GCC, but I'm pretty sure 4.2 had it. Probably much earlier versions than that.